# Submit a jquery form without closing the window too soon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I currently have a form that pops up in an IFrame. When submit is pressed, it actually executes a javascript function:

```
function goSubmit() {
    $( "#submitbutton" ).attr("disabled", true); 
    $( "form" ).submit(functon());   // submit form
    $('.modal_close').click();  // close iframe
}
```

My concern is that because the closing happens right after the submit, that perhaps the frame will be closed before the submit can take place. Is this a valid concern and how would I easily change this into an ajax call that waits for it to complete before performing the closing part?

*UPDATE*

I made a typo. I meant for the second item in the function to be the form selector. I've fixed that.

Comment: I don't quite know how you've got this setup but unless that's being submitted by AJAX then the submit will load the page defined in the form's `action` attribute and the modal will not be closed as the javascript on this page will be irrelevant on the new page.  Likewise, if the modal is closed then the submit won't fire properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can submit your form synchronously via ajax like that:

```
$.ajax({   
   type: 'POST',   
   url: $('#yourform').attr('action'),
   async: false,
   data: $('#yourform').serialize(),
   success: function(data){
      $('.modal_close').click();
   }
});
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: Is there no way to extrapolate the URL parameter from the form without having to specify it explicitly?

Comment: You could actually do somethink like `$("#myForm").attr("action");` to get this i think.

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind your click function to ajax:complete. This way it will be called after the form submit event is completed.

```
function goSubmit() {
    $( "#submitbutton" ).attr("disabled", true); 
    $("#myform").bind('ajax:complete', function() {
        $('.modal_close').click();  // close iframe
    });
}
```

Where myform is the id of your form. If you don't know it, you can do the following:

```
function goSubmit() {
    $( "#submitbutton" ).attr("disabled", true); 
    var $myform = $("#submitbutton").closest("form");
    $myform.bind('ajax:complete', function() {
        $('.modal_close').click();  // close iframe
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Their are two ways
1) you give time out for close
ex:

```
function goSubmit() {
    $( "#submitbutton" ).attr("disabled", true); 
    $( "#submitbutton" ).submit(functon());  // submit form
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.modal_close').click();  // close iframe
    },1000)
}
```

or
2)inside submit function call ajax call and wait for response
ex:

```
function goSubmit() {
    $( "#submitbutton" ).attr("disabled", true); 
    $( "#submitbutton" ).submit(functon(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     $.post('/path_to_submit',{
       parameters:parameters,
       .
       .
       },function(data){
         $('.modal_close').click(); // close iframe
        })
    });  // submit form

}
```